# How to programatically access current website status code in JS (chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension in which I need to collect the status code (200, 404, 401 etc.) of different websites that the user visits.

I am unable to find any library in chrome api to this, how can this be done?

Comment: Use chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived and read statusCode inside.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!
Somehow the `onHeadersReceived` only seems to work with the service-worker while I need to collect data in the content script.
What will be the best way to club the data of multiple `addListeners` in the service worker.

Sorry I am very new to TS/JS

Comment: Indeed webRequest must be used in the background script. You can store the value in a global object under a key like `details.tabId + ':' + details.frameId`. When your content script runs it'll [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and the background script's onMessage will do something like `sendResponse(myGlobalData[sender.tab.id + ':' + sender.frameId])`